# Rust: how can I have a struct which owns instances of another struct, while a third struct has references to the same instances

Tags: rust, move, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm solving a fairly classic "matchmaking" problem, commonly solved as an assignment-type problem in Operations Research.  I have the following structs represent a `Person` and a `Compatibility` between two people.

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

struct Compatibility<'a> {
    lhs: &'a Person,
    rhs: &'a Person,
    compatibility_score: f64,
}
```

This is fine.  Compatibilities don't *own* the persons they represent in their fields and as such just store references to them, but they must live *at least as long* as them, hence the lifetime param.  I can easily create some objects of both types like this:

```
fn create_model() {
    let persons = vec![
        Person{name: "Katie".to_string()},
        Person{name: "Helen".to_string()},
    ];
    let compatibilities = vec![
        Compatibility{lhs: &persons[0], rhs: &persons[1], compatibility_score: 50.0},
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to introduce a third struct, `Model`, which will own a vector of `Person` as well as a vector of `Compatibility`, and as such represent the data model which the problem will be run on.

```
pub struct Model {
    persons: Vec<Person>,
    compatibilities: Vec<Compatibility>,
}
```

Now this won't compile because `Compatibility` speficies a lifetime parameter, and so it seems that even though `Model` will *own* a vector of `Compatibility`, it still needs to specify a lifetime parameter, or otherwise we'll end up with `error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier`.  This makes some kind of sense to me - I mean, if an instance of `Compatibility` needs to live for at least as long as the `Person` instances it references, then the compiler needs to ensure that anything which *owns* a compatibility also lives as long.  So I add that in like so:

```
pub struct Model<'a> {
    persons: Vec<Person>,
    compatibilities: Vec<Compatibility<'a>>,
}
```

This is now building.  But now how do I actually create a `Model`?  Continuing from the earlier snippet, if I try to do this:

```
Model {
    persons,
    compatibilities
}
```

Then the compiler complains that I am moving `persons`, but it is still being borrowed by `compatibilities`.  The thing is, I *know* it's still being borrowed by compatibilities, and I'm trying to move *both of them* into the `Model` instance.  I need to somehow connect the two vectors so the compiler understands they **live together**.

Code is on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d870ed5d7743910266db049460cb5ff6) if you'd like to edit it yourself.

Comment: @SCappella thanks for the link - that question is from someone having exactly the same problem as me, yes.  I also understand the accepted/most-upvoted answer which explains *why* it can't be done, and the recommendation to "not attempt to put these items in the same structure together".  However, I'm still left in a position where I would like this "data model" to be stored somewhere so that the model can be passed around as a single unit encompassing the entire model.  It's possible I'll need to research the Rc type, but I'd be interested to hear suggestions towards simpler solutions.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a20534afbbe80ca5057eddf5d32eea5

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for giving it a crack.  I'll have to decide if going that way, with the model not owning the persons, is going to be the best for my use case or not.  Cheers.